# How offen Structure data gets updated (google webmaster tool)?

Tags: google-search-console

I found that some pages of my site is not being crawled in google webmaster tool from last 30 days. but some gets cowling in 2-3 days every time. is this normal?

And how often google updates Structure data errors in webmaster tool?

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

That is normal, some aspects can be quick but structured data can take a while.

Also to note, if the code is still broken then it's never going to update.

Have you tested it on Google's structured data testing tool?

Comment: thank. yes I did tested on GWT tool and there its showing all fine. but still its not getting update.